# returning custom error message for multiple variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller action with three variables, which I check for data validation and display a message if it fails. Here is my code for that:

```
    public ActionResult Validate(string fName, string lName, string sId)

    {    if (fName <> Data.GetFristName(fName))
            return Content("First Name " + fName + " not found");

         if (lName <> Data.GetFristName(lName))
            return Content("Last Name " + lName + " not found");

         if (sId <> Data.GetFristName(sId))
            return Content("Student ID " + sId + " not found");

        return Content("successful");

    }
```

Here I dont want to display seperate validation messages for each variables, Instead I want to go through each validation and then display one message listing all the failures. So if all the above three conditions would fail, I want to display:

> "Following Items were not found: First Name, Last Name, Student ID"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Validate(string fName, string lName, string sId)
{    
     string result = "";

     if (fName <> Data.GetFristName(fName))
     {
        result = result + fName;
     }
     if (lName <> Data.GetFristName(lName))
     {         
       result = result + lName );
     }
     if (sId <> Data.GetFristName(sId))
     {
        result = result + sId;
     }

    return "Following Items were not found: " + result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the built in validation summary that mvc provides. Here's a tutorial that highlights how to use it, it's quite useful:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/performing-simple-validation-cs

Answer (score 1):

If, for some reason, you don't want to use the built in validation, you can use the [ValidationResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411789%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class. You can pass a [collection of invalid members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411880%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or return a [ValidationResult.Success](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationresult.success%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).