# returning modelState error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller action where I perform some validations. I want to use ModelState.AddModelError to summarize the errors and display all at once, but without creating a view and using return content() instead. Is this possible? Here is my code so far:

```
    public ActionResult Validate(string lName, string fName)

    { 
       var lName= DataContext.LName(lName);
       var fName = DataContext.FName(fName);

        if (lName == null)
        ModelState.AddModelError("lName", "Last Name " + lName + " not found);

        if (fName== null)
        ModelState.AddModelError("fName", "First Name " + fName + " not found);

        return Content("Display Error Summary");

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the errors to MdoelState but you may need to test the validity also like so:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View();//Show error
    }
    else
    {
        return redirectToAction("Index")// No errors so move on
    }
```

And then in your Razor veiw

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've asked this question before: [returning custom error message for multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575953/returning-custom-error-message-for-multiple-variables/9576336#9576336)

You are attempting to mix two different ideas. I would recommend following LillyPop's answer or using the answer you selected from your earlier question.